# HTML: Picture/Image height percentage

Tags: html, image, height, percentage

Again me with one of my weird questions: What have I done wrong?!
Ok, seriously now, I somehow just got stuck while i was casually designing my webpage and then suddenly something weird happend.

---

I had a picture (`background-image` of a `div`) with a height percentage of 90%. For security reasons, so that it will display at least a bit appropriate on all display-sized devices, i used a fallback `min-height` from 300px. When i now started that same webpage again, suddenly it wouldn´t go to 90% of the webbrowsers site height, and instead, use the "fallback" of 300px. What has changed? After removing the fallback, the image didn´t show at all (and i´m using a pretty big gaming monitor), as if I would have a browser size of 0. What happened?

---

I can understand your need of a code, but that webpage is almost done and has some important information I can´t show. Therefore, please try to answer my question theoretically with the information given above. If you´d need more explanation because of my poor information, feel free to ask in a comment!
Thank you for all help I can get,
VicStudio

Comment: Create a separate example that demonstrates this behavior that you *can* post.

Comment: @JonB Sorry for not posting any code, I´ve solved by myself already ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made it by simply replacing the `90% with 90vh`. I bet there was something with the parent elements and stuff.
I hope this can help anybody in the future with the same problem.
VicStudio

Thanks for everybody who tried solving it :)